# Menu elements displaying locally but on the remote server

Tags: php, wordpress

The following bit of code works fine locally but on the remote server the second unsorted list is empty and I have no idea why because menu structures are identical in both places.

```
if (is_page()) {
    global $post;
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'main-menu' );
    $post_ID = $post->ID;

    echo '<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked nav-sidebar-pills">';
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_post_permalink($post_ID) . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a>';
    echo '<ul class="sub-menu">';

    foreach ($menu as $item) {
      if ($post_ID == $item->object_id) { $menu_parent = $item->ID; }
      if (isset($menu_parent) && $item->menu_item_parent == $menu_parent) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . $item->url . '"">'. $item->title . '</a></li>';
    }
  }
  echo '</ul>';
  echo '</li>';
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

After some debugging I managed to find that the $post_ID == $item->object_id condition always evaluates to false on the remote server. Can anyone tell me what might be the cause of this and how I can fix it? Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Is there anything in `$menu` on the remote server? If so please provide this log `print_r() `. If it doesn't include any data, does the main-menu menu really exist on the remote server?

Comment: Yes, the $menu array on the remote server contains WP_Post Object's, same as on the local side. I also added an echo statement in the foreach loop to print out $item->ID and they are getting displayed in both places. I'll provide the logs tomorrow because atm I don't have access to those files. Thanks for your help.